# Is there any existing mathematical work which connects the "entropy" with the "arrow of time"?

Tags: time, entropy

I have seen a lot of discussions connecting *entropy* with the *arrow of time*. One of them is a youtube link recently I saw : [Why is Time a One-Way Street? by Leonard Susskind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhnKBKZvb_U)

My question is this: Lot of time we associate the asymmetry in time (past to future) to *increase in average entropy*. Is there any mathematical work which connects these concepts?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376717/is-there-a-mathematical-relationship-between-time-and-entropy

Comment: In a way, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-theorem - with several caveats.

Comment: @valerio92 : What should I do now? Should I delete the question? Actually I searched before, but never found this one :(

Comment: If you feel that your question is answered by answers found on the other post, then I will propose to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: OK I will flag it as duplicate.

Comment: There is no empirical evidence that entropy in any closed system increases over time. In fact, it is in contradiction with the law that energy cannot be created or destroyed.